# Weird issue with link around div

Tags: html

I am having an issue with wrapping an `<a>` tag around a `<div>`. In my code, it looks like this:

```
<a href="/students/"><div class='tile tile-tall span6 bg-lightblue'></div></a>
```

but the link never fires when clicked. I checked it out in Chrome's inspector and for some reason it looks like this:

```
<a href="/students/"></a><div class='tile tile-tall span6 bg-lightblue'></div>
```

What's really confusing is that I use this code for 10 other `<div>` and links on the same page and they work fine.

Does someone have any idea as why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle that shows this error? I whipped up one that seems to work as you wrote it, so maybe something else in your HTML/JS is messing your anchor tag up.

**http://jsfiddle.net/T79Lj/**

EDIT: I suspect you have an improperly-closed tag somewhere. This may help, if my shot in the dark is correct: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Seems to be working ok. I added the link text http://jsfiddle.net/ZmF96/ <a href="/students/"><div class='tile tile-tall span6 bg-lightblue'></div>link</a> As DesertIvy mentioned, could you please add more details?

Comment: Yeah, i'll take a look when I get to my code here in a bit.

Comment: @DesertIvy I can't figure it. Validator didn't have any issues, I used an unclosed tag tool just to be positive and it didn't find anything. I'm just going to switch it to the anchor being inside the div and have it fill the div.

Comment: Please post more code to a JSFiddle page so it will be easier for us to help. Without more context, the best we can do is guess. Putting an anchor in the div will not work, since anchors must be applied to either text or an element. It will render fine, but you will have no space to click on it.

Comment: @DesertIvy if I have `style="display: block; height: 100%; width:100%"` it should and does work properly